# Running Smoothwall in Virtualbox

Tags: firewall, virtualbox

Okay so here's my deal,I need to run Smoothwall in a VM using Virtualbox running on a host PC with two physical NICs. I have some roommates and we are all sharing one internet connection which unfortunately has bandwidth caps. Among other things we need to monitor everyone so we can see who exactly is using the most bandwidth. I would like to use Smoothwall but am having trouble setting it up.

I would like it so that all traffic running across the wifi router goes through Smoothwall so that anyone who connected to the wifi smoothwall would see, log, and police.

Can someone point me to a good resource for setting this kind of thing. I know it's bad to use VM for this but this it's how we HAVE to run it. Here are some specs:

- Wifi router flashed with mini version of DD_WRT
- host PC with two physical NICs with windows XP as native OS
- Smoothwall running in a VM on the host PC

Now what research I have done mentions bridging one of the host NICs with the Virtualbox network adapter, but I'm not really grasping the whole concept of bridging network connections.

Right now Smoothwall it's running in a VM and I can access the settings page from my laptop, but the host has no internet connection (I can remote into the host though so the host does have internal connection) and smoothwall only shows a green plug/connector on its setup home page.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: I would suggest setting Smoothwall up as a transparent proxy, configuring DD-WRT to forward all traffic destined to leave the network to Smoothwall instead of the default gateway, but then I discovered this post: http://www.edugeek.net/forums/internet-related-filtering-firewall/53975-smoothwall-transparent-proxy-one-one-port-only.html

You might want to check this out.

Answer (score 0):

Having the WiFi in-front of the Smoothwall will make it hard to monitor the traffic in Smoothwall.

And connect the WiFi Routers Witch Port to the "Internal" port of the VM.
And disable the DHCP services in the WiFi router.